# R Shiny dataTableOutput don't work if using loop of reactive image

Tags: r, loops, image-processing

I'm using R software and EBImage package to image analysis.
I have an image with several frames that i load locally. 
I want to show a dataTable output of features (compute.Features.basic). I want to bind each dataframe (each frame) to a total one. But it doen't work properly. If i do the same with a non reactive image, it works ok. So, it's something about the reactive image.
Here is an example:

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

shinyApp(
   ui = fluidPage(
     fileInput('input.image',""),
     dataTableOutput("tabledata")
     ),



   server = function(input, output) {
     # Load Image
     img <- reactive({
         if (is.null(input$input.image))
         return(NULL)
         x <- readImage(input$input.image$datapath)
         })
     # Modified Image
     img_bw <- reactive({
        req( img() )
        x <- img()
        x <- gblur(x, sigma = 5)
        x <- thresh(x, w = 15, h = 15, offset = 0.05)
        x <- bwlabel(x)
        })

     # Create empty datagrame
        dt <- data.frame()
     # Calculate cell features for each frame and rbind frame-dataframe to total
        data <- reactive({
             for (i in 1:numberOfFrames(img())){
             dt <- rbind(dt, computeFeatures.basic(img_bw()[,,i], img()[,,i]))
             }
        })

  # Otuput
  output$tabledata <- renderDataTable(data())
}
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved simply introducing the creation of temporal dataframe into the reactive function and calling the dataframe:

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
 fileInput('input.image',""),
 dataTableOutput("tabledata")
 ),



server = function(input, output) {
 # Load Image
 img <- reactive({
     if (is.null(input$input.image))
     return(NULL)
     x <- readImage(input$input.image$datapath)
     })
 # Modified Image
 img_bw <- reactive({
    req( img() )
    x <- img()
    x <- gblur(x, sigma = 5)
    x <- thresh(x, w = 15, h = 15, offset = 0.05)
    x <- bwlabel(x)
    })


 # Calculate cell features for each frame and rbind frame-dataframe to total
    data <- reactive({
         # Create empty datagrame
            dt <- data.frame()
         # Use dt dataframe
         for (i in 1:numberOfFrames(img())){
         dt <- rbind(dt, computeFeatures.basic(img_bw()[,,i], img()[,,i]))
         }
         # Print dt dataframe
          dt
    })

  # Otuput
   output$tabledata <- renderDataTable(data())
  }
  )
  }
```